# Execute multiple if loops

Tags: python, loops

Is there a way to run and execute multiple if loops? For an example something like this:

```
x = 1
b = 1
for a in range(100):
    if x == 1:
        print "foo"
    if b == 1:
        print "bar"
```

This would give a 100 "foo"s but is it possible to execute both if statements so I could
get something like a 100 "foobar"s? I'm not looking for a nested if loop solution but something where the runtime actually checks an if condition executes it and goes onto the next if statement instead of starting the whole loop over.

EDIT: All answers were good so I picked a random one.

EDIT: Wow, ran my original code and it gave me a 100 "foobar"s? I could sworn it gave me a 100 "foo"s .. I must be tired..

Comment: as written this won't give 100 "foo"s. It'll give 1, on the second pass of the iteration. `a = 1` at the beginning, but then `a` is assigned the loop variable (`a=0`, `a=1`, `a=2`, etc). it'll print 100 "bar"s though, since `b` never changes

Comment: actually if you run it, it gives you a 100 "foo"s but I'll change my post for understandability.

Comment: ...what's an "if loop"? As *currently* written, you get 100 `foo`s and 100 `bar`s on alternating lines.

Comment: I think you need to make your example slightly more detailed.  Right now, nobody can tell what you actually want because the comparisons don't actually do anything, nor does the loop index.  You may find that if you concretely explain what you are trying to do, the solution will become obvious.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would make it easier:

```
a = 0
b = 0
value = 0
for value in range(100):
    if a == value and b == value:
        print "foo bar"
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
```

Or, use a comma:

```
a = 0
b = 0
value = 0
for value in range(100):
    if a == value:
        print "foo", #HERE IS THE ELUSIVE COMMA!
    if b == value :
        print "bar"
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
```

Both work. :)

The comma works the same way as a regular print statement would work: `print 'hello', 'hi'` = `hello hi`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0
b = 0
value = 0
for value in range(100):
    if a == value:
        print "foo"
    if b == value :
        print "bar"
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are looking for.  The for loop executes both if statements on every iteration.  The second one always succeeds because `b` is not changing.  Also, the `a=1` at the top doesn't do anything -- you don't need to initialize loop variables before a loop like you do in C.

Here is my stab at what you are looking for:

```
for a,b in zip(range(100), range(100)):
   if a==1:
       print "foo"
   if b==1:
       print "bar"
```

Here is what this does:  zip() allows you to iterate over multiple things at once.  In this case, two (identical) range sequences, but they don't have to be.  You can check each variable independently.

Comment: He's edited his question, there's no `a=1` any more.

Comment: Could I use this with an infinite while loop somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good assistance here.

I'd probably do this:

```
a = 1
b = 1
for x in range(0, 100):
    build_string = ""
    if a is 1:
        build_string += "foo"
    if b is 1:
        build_string += "bar"
    print build_string
```